# Dynamic programming - Finding columns that maximize score

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Let's say I'm initializing a random Dataframe as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
```

Now, let's say `score(matrix)` is a function that takes a subset of the dataframe and computes a score.

I want to find the a subset of `df` that maximizes the score. All the rows must be included, but the columns don't need to be contiguous. In other words, I can create a subset of `df` to pass into `score()` only using the columns of `df`.

My initial approach was to start from the first column, then concatenate the second column and if the score increases, then keep the column, otherwise, keep moving to the next column. **In the end, I want the top `x` columns that maximize score where `x<10`.**

I feel like my solution still won't find the optimum solution, because since I'm always starting from the first column, it will always be in my solution. But what if the optimum solution doesn't include the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how worried you are about efficiency, you could do a nested `for` loop like:

```py
for i in range(numberOfColumns):
   for j in range(numberOfColumns):
      if i == j:
         continue
      else: 
         #code
```

which would use each column (index `i`) as the starting column, then apply your method of concatenating/checking every other column (index `j`) and skipping `j` if it's already been added.

Comment: Even then, the best solution could be something like columns 1, 3, 4, 5. But 1,2,3,4 could be accepted simply because the score still increases by adding column 2. Hence, something more sophisticated needs to happen than my greedy solution.

Comment: Very true - I'm assuming you don't want a brute force method that just checks every single combination, too.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely what I want to avoid. Hence why I tagged the question as DP, hoping someone knows a DP way.

Comment: Should have thought of that before I answered  Should I delete my answer then?